# sonar issue assign plugin

Tags: svn, sonarqube

We are currently using SonarQube 4.1 and looking to upgrade Sonar to use new features like functionality to automatically assign issue to the developer who has created the issue (issue creator), reporting on newly added and fixed issue count per developer etc. 
We use SVN 1.6 and 1.7 as version control tool with tortoiseSVN as client. We trigger Sonar analysis via Team City.

After going through SonarQube notes and other available information, I could think of following two options:

1. Upgrade to SonarQube 4.5 LTS
2. Upgrade to SonarQube 5.1

I have also gone through plugin version matrix at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix to identify Sonar support for various plugins.

I have following questions:

1. If we choose option 1, I think we can use Issue Assign plugin to automatically assign issues to issue creator. Even though Sonar 4.5 LTS does not support SVN as per plugin version matrix, we should still be able to use Issue Assign plugin to act as an interface between Sonar and SVN to automatically assign issue to issue creator. Am I right?
2. If we choose option 2, as per Sonar notes, Sonar 5.1 has a feature to automatically assign issues to user.  Does that mean there is no need to use Issue Assign plugin with Sonar 5.1 as this functionality is in-built in Sonar 5.1?
3. If we choose option 2, Issue Assign plugin 1.6 is supported by Sonar 5.1 as per plugin version matrix but I have seen couple of posts where people have mentioned that Issue Assign plugin is not supported by Sonar 5.1. Has anyone tried this yet?
4. If we want to automatically create JIRA from newly created Sonar issues, how can we do that?
5. Is Sonar 5.1 stable enough to be used for analyzing code base of more than 600,000 lines of code or should we stick with 4.5 LTS version?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question 1: I don't know where you saw that version 4.5 does not support SVN but we use it everyday in our infrastructure and the analysis is able to identify the violations, the creator and assign the issues accordingly.

About using version 5.x, I would recommend you to stick with 4.5 LTS for a while until version 5 is a bit more mature. Some of the plugins are not compatible with version 5.x (for example sonar-cxx for C/C++ code). As far as I can tell, Sonar team are moving towards integrating some of the plugins into the core, so it is possible that there is no need for an external plugin for the issus assignment.

Hopefully, my answer helps you to clarify some of your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We have upgraded Sonar to 5.1 in test environment and noticed that issue assign is already integrated with SonarQube and it does not required any separate plugin installation though I am not able to use it to assign issues by SCM metrics. It might be configuration issue. I have posted another question regarding this new issue.